# Can stainless steel or galvinized screws be used indoors on non-pressure treated wood?

Tags: screws, pressure-treated

I assume yes and there is no harm or downside, besides these screws being more expensive than non-coated screws.

Answer (score 2):

Stainless steel is more brittle than the steel commonly used for screws. In some cases I have twisted off long ss screws. This may be a critical deficiency in some applications.

I use stainless steel exclusively for installing grab bars in showers. These are ss screws which come with the bars. In dry situations I use whatever I have except never drywall screws.

I once tried to use long ss screws to secure an owl box to the trunk of an oak tree and I twisted off the screws. I then used deck screws with no problem.

[BoltDepot](https://www.boltdepot.com/fastener-information/materials-and-grades/materials.aspx)

> Stainless steel is an alloy of low carbon steel and chromium for
>   enhanced corrosion characteristics. Stainless steel is highly
>   corrosion resistant for the price. Because the anti-corrosive
>   properties are inherent to the metal, it will not lose this resistance
>   if scratched during installation or use.
>
> It is a common misconception that stainless steel is stronger than
>   regular steel. In fact, due to their low carbon content, many
>   stainless steel alloys cannot be hardened through heat treatment.
>   Therefore, when compared to regular steel, the stainless alloys used
>   in bolts are slightly stronger than an un-hardened (grade 2) steel but
>   significantly weaker than hardened steel fasteners. Unless great care
>   is taken, stainless fasteners are susceptible to seizing up during
>   installation, a phenomenon known as galling.
>
> Most stainless steel fasteners are much less magnetic than regular
>   steel fasteners though some grades will be slightly magnetic.

Comment: Fully agree,+. I would use SS screws if I had them handy in just about everything.

Comment: Ok so this is fine to do, just not the opposite (non-galvinized screws outdoors and/or in pressure treated wood)?